# Error when destructuring values from useContext in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm a bit new to TypeScript, but I LOVE it.

When I try to destructure my `Context` in React using `useContext` I get some errors that I don't know why I'm getting.

The error: `Property 'nftContract' does not exist on type 'Web3 | null'.ts(2339)`

Context File

```
export interface Web3 {
  gameContract: Contract | string;
  nftContract: Contract | string;
  provider: Provider | string;
  account: string;
  etherBalance: string;
  setWeb3?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Web3>>;
}

export const Web3Context = createContext<Web3 | null>(null);

export const Web3Provider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [
    { gameContract, nftContract, provider, account, etherBalance },
      setWeb3
    ] = useState<Web3>({
      gameContract: '',
      nftContract: '',
      provider: '',
      account: '',
      etherBalance: ''
  });

  return (
    <Web3Context.Provider
        value={{
            provider,
            gameContract,
            nftContract,
            account,
            etherBalance,
            setWeb3
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </Web3Context.Provider>
  );
```

File consuming Context (Context has been wrapped properly in the main index/app file.)

```
const MintNFTForm = () => {
   // Property 'nftContract' does not exist on type 'Web3 | null'.ts(2339)
   const { nftContract } = useContext(Web3Context);
}
```

Anything helps,thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Destructure the value only after it has been checked for not being `null`:

```
const MintNFTForm = () => {
   const ctxt = useContext(Web3Context);
   if (ctxt == null) return <div>No context yet</div>;

   // `ctxt` is now guaranteed to not be `null`, safe to destructure
   const { nftContract } = ctxt;
}
```

The code is initializing the context's value to `null` and declaring that its type can be `null` so any code referencing it must account for that case:

```
export const Web3Context = createContext<Web3 | null>(null);
```

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you! I'll try this. How can I set the `createContext` value to be empty? I would like for it to not have the value `null` & just the `Web3`, but I also would like to not pass anything to `createContext`. Is there a way to leave it blank? When I try to leave it blank it complains that it needs to be passed in 1 arguement.

Comment: The error I get if I change it to `export const Web3Context = createContext<Web3>();` is: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(383, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.`

Comment: I would also like to be able to restructure the context without having to check for `null` since it'd be a lot cleaner to do so.

Comment: What is a `Web3`? Is there a default Web3 you can pass to `createContext`? "Cleaner" is a subjective term here; checking for null is correct since the value is initialized to null, this looks clear to me!

Comment: Web3 is something in Blockchain. Based on your example: what if I wanted to not return anything because my component has other stuff it needs to render?

Comment: "not return anything" <- not sure what that means. Checking for `null` is correct. Not sure what outcome you want? What do you want to render before you have fetched the initial value of the `createContext`? What do you want to render once you have the `Web3` object?

Comment: You could do it in a cleaner way like so `const nftContract = useContext(Web3Context)?.nftContract` it's a on liner that checks for `null`